# Android: Who start Activity

Tags: android

I have 3 activity: Activity1, Activity2, Activity3. Activity1 and Activity3 can start Activity2:

> startActivity (new Intent(this,Activity2));

How in Activity2 I can check which class start Activity2 ? Is there any way to take information from Intent ? Thanks...

I dont whant to put anything in Intent. I think I dont need that. When I start intent I already saying from what context I do that (new Intent(`*this*`,Activity2)). And this "this" I want to recognize in Activity2 !!! Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, you do want to put something into the `Intent` because there's no way to get at the supplied `Context` on the other side. Also, it's the Android way of doing this, don't fight it :)

Comment: Check out my answer below for a technical explanation why your `this` is lost; too long for a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass that information in the "extra" `Bundle` of your `Intent`:

In `Activity1`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("caller", "activity1");
startActivity(intent);
```

In `Activity2`:

```
String caller = getIntent().getStringExtra("caller");
```

There's also get/put extra methods for other data types like `boolean`, `int`, etc.

---

As for why you cannot access the `Context` you supplied when creating the `Intent` on the other side:

The only thing that Android does with the supplied `Context` (i.e. your `this`) is to create a [`ComponentName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) from it. That class only keeps the *package* of the supplied `Context` and discards anything else.

So you theoretically could put your activities into different packages and then go `getIntent().getComponentName().getPackageName()` on it at the receiving end -- but please don't. `Intent` extras is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

To send:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2)
intent.putExtra("activityNumber", 1);
startActivity(intent);
```

To receive:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    activitySource = extras.getInt("activityNumber");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass along information between Activities using an `Intent`s "Extras":

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
newIntent.putExtra("CalledFrom", Activity1.class.getSimpleName())
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Then in the receiving `Activity` you can call:

```
String fromActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("CalledFrom");
```

You can pass basic types as well as Object's which implement the `Parcelable` interface

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding information to your Intent.

for example:

```
public Intent putExtra (name, value)
```

In the newly started service you can then look up this information.

Or you can use the addFlags method like in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent` data members to pass parameters to your activities. There's an `extras` data member that is a `Bundle` of anything you want - a general-purpose name/value collection.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2);
i.putExtra("From", "Activity1");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in Activity2 you can examine the starting intent for extra data and find this out.

Alternatively, you can use intent `data`, settable with `setData()`. `Data` member has the format of the URI, somewhat unfriendly to passing structured information. It's slightly less typing though.

Comment: Any reason why you create a separate bundle `bun` to set it into the intent's existing `extra` bundle?

Answer (score 0):

in the intent that starts activity you can always pus flag as

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.putExtra("startedBy","A1");
//or 
//i.putExtra("startedBy","A2");
//...
```

and than in the receiving activity use
in the on activityresult method

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
if(intent.getStringExtra("startedBy").equals("a1"){
//do somth
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions that use the simple name of the class cause `ClassNotFoundException`s. The solution I use is similar, but uses the canonical name:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
newIntent.putExtra("caller", Activity1.class.getCanonicalName())
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Then in the other activity

```
String caller = getIntent().getStringExtra("caller");
Class callingClass = Class.forName(caller);
```