# Android: Did launcher or different app start my app?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to find out, if my Android App was opened by the launcher or by some third party app?

Something like this maybe?
[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433612/android-who-start-activity)

I am trying to build an app that can toggle torch. Which already works (I am new to Java and Android). But I want Bixby Button on my Samsung phone to open the app and then toggle torch automatically. Bixby is able to open a app since the newest version.

I found out, that if I open the app from the launcher and resume, it's the same instance. But if Bixby opens the app, it seems to be a new instance every time.
And I don't want to use Availability Service to receive bixby button event.

kind regards

Comment: you want to open your application from another app right ?

Comment: @RohitSingh, no, he wants to know if his app was opened from the launcher, or from the other app.

Comment: just FYI: The launcher is the same app as any other app.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko, yes your right.
Is there some string somewhere, if the launcher or the other app "opened" my app?

Comment: Thank you, I try this out and respond.

Comment: Typically you get `ACTION_MAIN` if your app was started from the launcher, and `ACTION_VIEW` if your app was started from another app. It's not really clear what the _actual_ problem is though. What is the problem that you think you could solve if you were able to separate between these two cases?

Comment: Can you give me a litte example how to get the action? Sorry I am really new...

Answer (score 0):

@Vladyslav Matviienko, thank you for [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304304/how-to-get-the-sender-of-an-intent):

This seems to work:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Uri uri = this.getReferrer();
    if (uri==null) textView.append("Host: null");
    else textView.append("Host: " + uri.toString());
}
```

When opened by launcher, uri is "null", but when opened by bixby, it is "android-app://com.samsung.android.bixby.agent"

EDIT: On a second try launcher is "android-app://com.sec.android.app.launcher".